# Stripe - Check Card balance

Tags: python, stripe-payments, credit-card

I wonder if it is possible to check if a (debit or credit) card has enought balance to pay for a (not so far) future charge.

I have read the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_card) but I can't find any about if this is possible or not (I hope it is). I know [Stripe validate every card](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-check-whether-a-card-is-valid-without-charging-it-at-the-same-time) but I need to know if it has enought balance for the amount will be charged later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to know if a card is able to charge a card is to actually charge (or at least authorize it). Stripe allows you to authorize a card for up to a week (basically just hold a charge as pending for 72 hours) before you "capture" it.

Even if a card has enough available funds / balance to pay for a charge, that is no guarantee that a bank would approve it.

Comment: I know this won't guarantee a future success payment, but I need to do it. Do you have a link to Stripe docs for pending charge? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge note the capture parameter

Comment: This essentially means that someone must prepare for rejection on server side as well. I try to do as much check as possible on the web front-end, so a request doesn't get to the server unnecessarily. But a charge can be denied even when the execution is on server side, no matter how much weight lifting the web front-end does.